# MySQL crossdata query

Tags: mysql

I have one database in MySQL. This DB has a table with 8 fields:

```
id
Type1
Type2
Type3
Type4
Type5
Type6
ProductPrice
```

Im using this Query to order and show the data:

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE Type6 = 4
ORDER By Type5 ASC, Type4 ASC, Type3 ASC, Type1 ASC
```

And this other query to show the same results, but with a type changed

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE Type6 = 3
ORDER By Type5 ASC, Type4 ASC, Type3 ASC, Type1 ASC
```

The ProductPrice where Type6=4 must be higher than where Type6=3, but manually checking this, I checked I did a wrong data injection in few ProductPrice fields.

How can I check which id's have ProductPrice higher than others, having in mind that we must compare Type6 = 3 < Type6 = 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is this: You mustn't join the tables by the Id because is a key field, and is unique. When you join two equal tables, you will lose the Id's with same Types, and different prices. Thanks to [smoore4](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1143681/smoore4)

```
SELECT *
FROM Table as t1
    INNER JOIN Table as t2 ON t1.Type1=t2.Type1
                           AND t1.Type2=t2.Type2
                           AND t1.Type3=t2.Type3
                           AND t1.Type4=t1.Type4
                           AND t1.Type5=t2.Type5
WHERE t1.Type6 = 3 AND t2.Type6 = 4
AND t1.ProductPrice > t2.ProductPrice
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically do an INNER JOIN on the same table, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table t1
  INNER JOIN Table t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.Type6 = 3
AND t2.Type6 = 4
AND t1.ProductPrice < t2.ProductPrice
```

Comment: Im a little confused, because in 

`WHERE t1.Type6 = 3
AND t2.Type6 = 4` 

The mysql is telling me 0 products...like if the sql recognize them as same table... (you cannot have type6 equals 3 and 4 at same time)

I guess is a problem with the Join... because with a OR I can see results

Comment: The query must be like this:
SELECT * FROM Table as t1
INNER JOIN Table as t2 ON t1.Type1=t2.Type1AND t1.Type5=t2.Type5 AND t1.Type3=t2.Type3 AND t1.Type4=t2.Type4 AND t1.Type4= t1.Type4
WHERE t1.IdPlazo = 3
AND t2.IdPlazo = 4
AND t1.Importe > t2.Importe


A lot of thanks @SQLDBA !!!!

Comment: Because the Id of the table is a key field! Is unique, if you use it to join the tables, the results match in id field, and I need to find the id's that concur in same Type's, but different prices.

Comment: Cool.  I am glad you got your answer.  Normally I test before posting but didn't have time.